# Using wcstod to convert zero value

Tags: c++, xml

Am using wcstod() to convert to numeric type text data which I read from an XML file:

```
double x;
BSTR name;
MSXML::IXMLDOMNodeListPtr theList;
MSXML::IXMLDOMNodePtr theItem;

//Some XML API here...

theItem = theList->Getitem(0);
theItem->get_text(&name);
x = wcstod(name,NULL);
```

the problem is that this function returns NULL upon failure, but sometimes I do want to read and convert the valid string L"0". 
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: There is no return statement shown. What returns `NULL`? Add error check for `Getitem` and `get_text`. If any of them fail then do not proceed.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani the returned value from wcstod is assigned to x. I can't discriminate between valid returned value of "0" to conversion failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) which will throw exception if the function fails.

Make sure `BSTR` is initialized to `NULL`. Add error check for `Getitem` and `get_text`

```
#include <string>

BSTR name = nullptr;
...
double x = 0;
if(name)
{
    try
    {
        x = std::stod(name);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        //error ...
    }
}
```